# How do I force a component to re-render in between synchronous requests? (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My goal is to make a series of requests, and upon the completion of each request, update text that indicates what step is currently being processed. Like so:

[image: Screenshot]

Before I get into specifics I'd like to address that as far as I know there are two ways to trigger a re-render

1. Use `setState`
2. Use `forceUpdate` (not recommended)

Neither of these methods are working in my case which is why I'm creating this question.

I read, as far as I understand, that updating state in async requests has issues with triggering re-renders. So I tried to process each async request synchronously with the recursive method `processRequests` at the bottom here:

```
process = () => {
    this.setState( { processing: true } );

    const dir = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.MainBundleDir;

    const { item } = this.state;

    const requests = [
        {
            url: `${this.base_url}/${item.id}`,
            message: 'Loading model...',
            callback: function( res ) {
                return new Promise( resolve => {
                    const model_url = JSON.parse( res.data );
                    RNFetchBlob.config( {
                        path : `${dir}/model.obj`
                    } ).fetch( 'GET', model_url ).then( () => resolve() )
                } );
            }
        },
        {
            url: `${this.base_url}/${item.id}`,
            message: 'Loading texture...',
            callback: function( res ) {
                return new Promise( resolve => {
                    const texture_url = JSON.parse( res.data );
                    const split = texture_url.split( '.' );
                    const extension = split[ split.length -1 ];
                    RNFetchBlob.config( {
                        path : `${dir}/texture.${extension}`
                    } ).fetch( 'GET', texture_url ).then( () => resolve() )
                } );
            }
        }
    ];

    this.processRequests( requests );
};

requestFileAndDownload = ( url, callback ) => {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        RNFetchBlob.fetch( 'GET', url ).then( res => {
            callback( res ).then( () => {
                resolve();
            } )
        } );
    } );
};

processRequests = requests => {
    const request = requests.shift();

    const { url, message, callback } = request;

    console.log( 'message = ', message );

    this.setState( { processing_text: message } );

    this.requestFileAndDownload( url, callback ).then( () => {
        if( requests.length ) {
            this.processRequests( requests );
        }
    } );
};
```

The files are successfully downloaded but I cannot get the component to re-render in between requests. Even though the text in the state has definitely been updated, as indicated by console messages I've output:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried inserting `forceUpdate` in a bunch of different places, but I find in general that if I ever get to the point where I feel the need to try and use `forceUpdate` it never works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use the setState callback handler function in the processRequests call.

It will wait until setState finishes and the component re-renders before calling the next file download function.

```
this.setState( { processing_text: message }, () => {
  this.requestFileAndDownload( url, callback ).then( () => {
    if( requests.length ) {
        this.processRequests( requests );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I just realized I made a stupid mistake and the text was still hard coded as "Loading model..." after writing up this whole question... My code above works fine as it turns out. This is good to know so thanks though, didn't know you could do that with setState.